# How to do oauth 2.0 in electron shell

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, electron

I am trying to build an application which will consume an api. it has a oauth 2.0 authentication. my gui framework is electron shell (https://github.com/atom/electron) is there any framework or node package to do this easily ? My doubt is the callback URL is NATted behind some router. how do i do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a nice example of [how to do oAuth authentication in an electron app using Github API](https://www.manos.im/blog/electron-oauth-with-github/). Also if you search in github.com you will find a lot of projects using electron and implementing oauth like [Gitify does here](https://github.com/manosim/gitify/blob/master/src/js/reducers/auth.js).

Comment: The article suggests putting your client_secret in the source code. Do you know if this is safe to do?

Comment: The best practice is to put it in a config file, not in your version source code: see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/205608 When you post them as the article shows the secret key is traveling in the request body and since the github api is secured by https then it's secure to do it that way.

Comment: Thanks @matagus but I was referring more to the security of the configuration data in the build. I'll reiterate the question: can electron shell apps be decompiled somehow and make the source code readable?

Comment: The Gitify source mentioned in the answer is no longer there. I think this file contains what was pointed by the link: https://github.com/manosim/gitify/blob/master/src/js/utils/helpers.js

Comment: Both links are broken in the answer above.